# why IEEE 754 single precision has exponent range from -127 to 128 but not from -128 to 127

Tags: ieee-754, single-precision

In IEEE 754 single precision 8 bit exponent range is from -127 to 128 but not from -128 to 127

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this curious question. I can't see a duplicate. I imagine it has its roots in 2's complement 8 bit numbers.

Comment: It is because of [denormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) support.  [Quoting](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html): "With its `G' format, DEC's VAX disagreed with the K-C-S draft primarily in their treatments of underflow, which the VAX flushed to zero instead of handling gradually. Consequently their exponent biases and over/underflow thresholds differed; K-C-S let numbers grow twice as big as VAX did without overflowing. Exponent biases differed by 2".